# Screen Overlay Permissions

Tags: screen, overlay

So I downloaded Skype recently and ever since, all my apps have the prompt popping up asking for permission to use things such as gallery and camera. But when I press allow, it makes me go into an endless loop of turning off overlay apps. I have no clue how to stop this and allow the permissions. The app I am trying to use my gallery on is Instagram.

Comment: Permit the question: Did you download Skype from an official source? I'm not aware that (or why) Skype should use overlays causing other apps to ask for permissions. First upcoming suspicion is it's "something else" that came along.

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn off permissions of overlay apps, go to settings --> apps then click  the gear icon on the top right. Next under advanced, chose "Draw over other apps." Then you can turn off all the overlays you chose or tap "Enabled" in the top and switch it to "Disabled".

[image: settings]
[image: advanced]
[image: draw over other apps]
[image: enabled/disabled]

You can also uninstall the apps which are causing the overlay. For me, I had blue light filter installed and it didn't let me press allow since I had that on. Hope this helped!